# Qt, problem with QTimer while using QMessageBox in QkeyPressedEvent

Tags: qt, keypress, qtimer, qmessagebox

The function is :
When I press key up once, keyPress called , slot linked on QTimer called once, KeyReleased called, QTimer stoped.
When I keep pressing key up, key Press called, slot lined on QTimer called every 2s,
when I release key up, KeyReleased called, QTimer stopped.
Everthing goes well without QMessageBox. 
Problem is:
When I add QMessageBox in the slot,   KeyReleased will never be called and QTimer will never stoped.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    connect(&m_keyUpTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::slotKeyUpTimerTimeOut);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * e)
{
    if (e->isAutoRepeat()) {
        return;
    }
    switch (e->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
    {
        QMessageBox errorMsg;
        errorMsg.setWindowTitle("Press");
        errorMsg.show();


        if (!m_keyUpTimer.isActive() ) {
            m_keyUpTimer.start(2000);
        }
        break;
    }
    default: break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * e)
{
    if (e->isAutoRepeat()) {
        return;
    }
    switch (e->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
    {
        m_keyUpTimer.stop();
        QMessageBox errorMsg;
        errorMsg.setWindowTitle("Release");
        errorMsg.show();
        break;
    }

    default: break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::slotKeyUpTimerTimeOut() const
{
    QMessageBox errorMsg;
    errorMsg.setWindowTitle("Slot");
    errorMsg.show();
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: _When I add QMessageBox in the slot, KeyReleased will never be called and QTimer will never stoped._ I assume that the `QMessageBox` gets the focus after `errorMsg.show();`. Hence, it is the one which receives the `keyReleaseEvent()`. One idea might be to "steal the focus". However, an [Event Filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) could be a solution as well. (Even after stealing the focus from message box, the user could revert this by clicking on title of message box.)

Comment: I found the problem. KeyReleaseEvent isnt been stolen, but runned while you waiting on MsgBox. Cuz when you show MsgBox in WindowModal , other event will be dealed.

Comment: I'm aware that a `QMessageBox` ran with `QMessageBox::exec()` drives its own event loop (and is modal). However, you used `errorMsg.show();`. So, I was expecting that it would be non-modal. Thereby, I overlooked that it's a local variable in your code. Actually, I must admit I've never done it this way and would've expected that the message box would vanish immediately after the `show()` (at least, on Windows where I'm "at home"). If it doesn't then ... it blocks your global event loop and prevents obviously any further event handling in it (incl. `QTimer::timeout()` and `keyReleaseEvent()`).

Comment: _when you show MsgBox in WindowModal , other event will be dealed._ You probably meant: _when you show MsgBox in WindowModal , **no** other event will be dealed._ :-) (I tried to explain above why (I think) this is so.)

Comment: I still struggle a bit to believe that `errorMsg.show()` runs its own event loop. Are you sure you didn't use `errorMsg.exec()`? I just recalled [QMessageBox::exec()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec) to check whether I miss something. I hoped to find a specific note about `show()` and [Qt::WindowModal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) but I couldn't. The only thing is a note in [QMessageBox::QMessageBox()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#QMessageBox-1) that I don't understand fully as I've never used macOS. Out of curiosity: on which OS are you?

Comment: I use windows10. But I think Mac or Windows doesnt matter. When I use exec(), instead of show(), problem solved. I think in the show(), there are code like processevent(). So when the MSG window wait for respond, code in keypressed paused in show(). But the code in keyReleased goes through. So QTimer stopped first in keyRelease , then started again in keyPressed after show.